# how can i find out which part of my application uses .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, ms-publisher

is there a way to find out which part of my application uses framework 4 client profile or whatever.

I have a simple application which i published through the visual studio 2010 publish wizard when i install it anywhere else it is downloading 4.0 and in some places it is just complaining the application cannot install because the framework 4.0 is not installed.

Problem is i have done nothing fancy that needs framework 4.0. But still may be a minor part of my app uses something or i dont know what it is. So can any one tell me how to find out what part of my app exactly uses framework 4.0. so that i can change it and find a workaround for that.

Comment: both these answers are not the ones i expected later i found out that there is a 3rd party tool to do this.

Comment: Ahh, in that case, can you post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you compiled the project using Visual Studio, you can change the target framework on the project properties page, Application tab.

Project > "My Project" Properties > Application, and change the target framework :)

Answer (score 1):

In your project settings, switch the target framework to "3.5". Then the compiler will complain about any non-3.5 features that you use.